# Unordered_mutlimap iterator erase

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, unordered-map, unordered-multimap

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_multimap<int, int> uomap;
    typedef unordered_multimap<int, int>::iterator iter;

    uomap.insert({ 2, 30 });
    uomap.insert({ 1, 40 });
    uomap.insert({ 3, 60 });
    uomap.insert({ 2, 20 });
    uomap.insert({ 5, 50 });

    for (auto iter = uomap.begin(); iter != uomap.end(); iter++)
        cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    int k = 0;
    for (auto iter = uomap.begin(); iter != uomap.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (k % 2 == 0)
        auto it = uomap.find(it);
        uomap.erase(it);
        k++;
    }
    
    /*
    auto it1 = uomap.find(2);
    uomap.erase(it1);
    */

    for (auto iter = uomap.begin(); iter != uomap.end(); iter++)
        cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And my issue would be in line 26 where I have a compiling issue. According to VisualStudio identifier "it" is undefined, but if I were to write the same thing outside of a "for" like in the commented section, the code would run just fine.

Basically I'm testing different ways of getting elements out of an unordered_multimap for another problem I have, but I just can't seem to get things to work. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You are trying to initialise `it` using the value of `it`. I'm sure you can see that does not make sense. The commented out code does compile, but it doesn't have the same problem, so it's not relevant. I'd like to suggest how to fix your code, but I'm not really sure what it is that you are trying to do. Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: You're attempting to use `it` in the same line that defines it: `auto it = uomap.find(it)`. I doubt this will compile, regardless of  where you put it.

Comment: It's seems that maybe you are trying to delete all the even elements from the map, is that correct? If so the correct code looks very different from what you have.

Comment: It is also completely unclear what the `for` loop is doing in the first place, iterating over the map but doing absolutely nothing, whatsoever, with the iterator. It seems to me like the first order of business here would be [to have a lengthy, in-depth discussion with your rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: is that so @john ? That's what I'm trying to achieve yeah, so what would the code look like?

Comment: Not sure if you forgot the brackets after if, or you mean only execute `uomap.find(it);` on the condition. In any case, you need to declare `it` before you use it. I think to VTC as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting all the even elements from an `unordered_map`

```
for (auto it = uomap.begin(); it != uomap.end(); )
{
    if (it->first % 2 == 0)
        it = uomap.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

This the standard technique, the key part is that you do **not** increment the iterator when you do the erase, instead the return value from `erase` is the new iterator value. This is because erasing an element from a map also *invalidates* any iterator pointing to that element. Any operation on an invalidated iterator causes undefined behaviour, even just incrementing it. Conveniently though the `erase` method returns the next iterator.

Comment: I'd say using the erase/remove idiom would be the standard technique. Not a hand-rolled loop.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, but this is closer to the original code, so hopefully is more instructive. Remove_if might be beyond the OP.

Comment: thank you, I implemented this in my code and it wokrs. I honestly feel really stupid reading all these comments

Comment: @Julia No problem, glad to help. You sometimes need a thick skin to post here

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to john's answer, erasing elements with an even key, using C++20

```cpp
auto is_even = [](auto keyval) { return keyval.first % 2 == 0; };
std::erase_if(uomap, is_even);
```